# how to create a RadioButtonList (bound from a db) within the ItemTemplate of a repeater dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, repeater, radiobuttonlist, html.radiobuttonlist

how to bind radio-button list items to repeater?
I have a repeater control. I need to get the items which are already existed in radio-button list.

Answer (score 0):

You should use table in repeater with radio button instead of RadioButtonList with same group as

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <table>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="OptionsRadioButton" runat="server" Width="332px" Text='<%E# val("Title") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop and find each RadioButtonList in Repeater and insert data

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptComments.Items)
{
string value = (item.FindControl("rptComments") as RadioButtonList).SelectedValue;
//Code to insert data here
}
```